# When i press tab in sublime text 2 it does 2 different things

Tags: sublimetext2

In one computer that i have if write `html` and press `TAB` it will head whole html layout, very convenient.

In other computer, it just adds `<html> </html>`.

So why i want it to behave like the first one.
It may not be just computer but how i setup files etc.

Comment: Do you have a plug-in installed in the second version, such as zen-coding, now named Emmet? Try disabling some plug-ins.

Comment: how do i disable it without removing

Comment: If you have Package Control (which is essential for ST) choose the Preferences menu, Package Control, and List or Disable Package(s).

Comment: ok after disabling its working..how can i fix that. I want to use emmet

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, thanks to comment from Andrew, i have figured out that package called Emmet was messing this up but for good as it provides a better way to do things. 
try `html:5`

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/03/26/goodbye-zen-coding-hello-emmet/

Answer (score 0):

FWIW In case there are other snippets that you want to use that conflict with the Emmet plug-in:

Find the file `html.sublime-snippet` in the **Packages Folder\HTML**. Edit it and change the trigger from `html` to some other phrase that won't conflict with Emmet shortcuts.